# AngularJS ui-router re-render

Tags: angularjs

I using ui-router to render a view. After render, how to re-render the view after perform some activity in the view (example return data after searching).

My problem is after render the View, I click a search button to search some records from database. But I don't know how to render the View again. Anything that I need to do in the View's search button?

Hope can give some example to me on how to solve it. Thank you.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){

$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'home/Main'
})
```

})

```
 <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div ui-view></div>   //render menu content
</div>
```

Above is Menu Layout

```
<input id="txtsearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search member ID or email" />
<input type="submit" id="btnsearch" value="Search" />
```

Above is View

Comment: I would suggest adding more content to this question, to help us get to the answer that you need to resolve this problem. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and review your question.

Comment: @Hopeful Llama: I already added some of my code. Please give some advise. Thx.

Comment: Is there any functionality tied to your submit button?

Comment: @Hopeful Llama: Not ye. I want to fire an action in Controller. But i dont know how to render in the ui-view. Any proper way to call action in controller and render in the view?

Comment: With AngularJS, the view should render automatically whenever anything in the Controller/Scope changes.

Comment: @Hopeful Llama: can show some sample?